# Getting function to run as user types

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, keyup

I have a phone number input that I am trying to get the dashes to appear in the number as the user types.

I am wanting the number to appear as 555-555-5555.

The function works for the most part, but the dashes aren't entered until after the whole number is entered. I am using the `keyup` function, which I thought would solve this, but no luck.

Does anyone have any recommendations as to what I have to do to get the dashes to be entered as the user types in the digits?

```js
$('#phone').keyup(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{3})\-?(\d{4})/,'$1-$2-$3'))
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="contact-label">Phone Number:</label>
  <input type="tel" class="contact_input" name="phone" id="phone">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code slightly to produce something that I think is a little easier to read, but still does the job.

I just evaluated the length of the `<input />` tag's value on each `.keyup()` event and then augmented the value accordingly. Take a look at the snippet below:

**--UPDATE--**

After comments regarding backspacing issues I added a couple lines of code that seem to fix the issue:

First I checked for either backspace or delete `.keyup()` events to prevent the formatting code from interfering with correcting errors in the number.

I also added a few checks, and a global `formatFlag` variable to ensure that if the user backspaces to an awkward index like 3 or 6(where hyphens would normally be added), that formatting would resume as normal on the next `.keyup()` event.

```js
let formatFlag = false;

$(function(){

  $('#phone').keyup(function(evt) {
      
      let modifiedValue = $(this).val().replace(/-/g, "");
      
      if(evt.keyCode == 8 || evt.keyCode == 46) { //8 == backspace; 46 == delete
        
        //Checks whether the user backspaced to a hyphen index
        if(modifiedValue.length === 3 || modifiedValue.length === 6) { 
        
          //Checks whether there is already a hyphen
          if($(this).val().charAt($(this).val().length - 1) !== '-') {
          
            formatFlag = true; //Sets the format flag so that hyphen is appended on next keyup()
            
          } else {         
          
            return false; //Hyphen already present, no formatting necessary
            
          }
          
        } else {
        
          formatFlag = false;
          
        }
        
        return false; //Return if backspace or delete is pressed to avoid awkward formatting
      }
      
      if(!!formatFlag) {
      
        // This re-formats the number after the formatFlag has been set, 
        // appending a hyphen to the second last position in the string
        $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, $(this).val().length - 1) + '-' + 
        $(this).val().slice($(this).val().length - 1));
        
        formatFlag = false; //Reset the formatFlag
      }
      
      if(modifiedValue.length % 3 == 0) {
      
        if(modifiedValue.length === 0 || modifiedValue.length >= 9){
        
          return false;
          
        } else {
        
          $(this).val($(this).val() + '-');
          return;
          
        }
      
      }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label class="contact-label">Phone Number:</label>
  <input type="tel" class="contact_input" name="phone" id="phone" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I am noticing if you delete the number, it either gets caught at a dash and won't delete or if you highlight and delete it all the dashes remain.

Comment: I see! I've updated my answer. The keyup() function now exits before the formatting code is reached in the case of backspace/delete events. There were also issues where the hyphens would format strangely if the user backspaced to an index that usually contained a hyphen(string index 3 & 6). It's a quick-and-dirty solution, but it should help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect. I appreciate you helping out again!